# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple a TODO list app in ReactJS. My basics of React are not very clear so I am stuck here.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>React TODO</title>
    <script src="../../build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../../build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" lang="ja">
  var TodoList = React.createClass({

    Checked: function(e) {
    alert("Checked");
  },

  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(item) {
      return <li key={item.id}>{item.text}<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.Checked} /></li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
  }

});
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },

  onButtonClick: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([{text: this.state.text, id: Date.now()}]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.onButtonClick} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>
    
</body>

   
</html>
```

With every list generated, a checkbox is assigned to it .
Code works fine without onChange event to Checkbox. But when "Checked" function is assigned to it, error is generated.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need set `this` for `.map` (you can do that through second argument in [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```
return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem, this)}</ul>;
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26605/)

because now in `createItem` `this` refers to global (in browsers it will be `window`) score (or if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) `this` will be `undefined`)

as you use `babel` you also can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var createItem = (item) => {
  return <li key={item.id}>
    {item.text}<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.Checked} />
  </li>;
};

return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26612/)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

you can go with Alex Solution but you can also achieve the same thing by changing only two place like

```
var that=this;
var createItem = function(item) {
      return <li key={item.id}>{item.text}<input type="checkbox" onChange={that.Checked} /></li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make createItem a method of TodoList class. The "this" reference is not being resolved as right now its a local function of render method. On a side note, React follows camel casing for handlers. Please rename the Clicked method to onChange, onChecked or onCheckClicked.