# ReactJS ES6 function binding - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on ReactJS with multiple components in parent-child mode. In the following example, update function is passed on to the Note component (child) from Board component (parent). When I execute the code, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined` error and I have a bind(this) in the constructor.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Note from './note';

export default class Board extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       notes: [
        'Call Bill',
        'Email list',
        'Fix evernote tags'
       ]
    };
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

 update(newText,i){
    alert('update triggered');
    var arr = this.state.notes;
    arr[i]=newText;
    this.setState({notes:arr});
  };

  eachNote(note,i){
    return(
      <Note key={i} index={i} onNoteChange={this.update}>{note}</Note>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board">
        { this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. And once the binding in place, I should be able to call this parent method in the child component right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Checked' of undefined - ReactJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629343/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-checked-of-undefined-reactjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` in `eachNote` does not refer to `Board`, it refers to global scope(*in browser it is `window`*) or if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)(*I think you use it*) it will be `undefined`, you need set it

```
{ this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote, this) }
                                    __^^^^___
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Alexander answer, you can bind `eachNote` to `this` in constructor too and it should work:

```
this.eachNote = this.eachNote.bind(this);
```